# How are custom ETW events enabled in Azure roles?

Tags: c#, azure, etw

In my components, I've created several sources of ETW events by deriving from the [`EventSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx) class:

```
[EventSource]
public class MessagingTrace : EventSource
{
    [Event(1)]
    public void MessageReceived(string address)
    {
        this.WriteEvent(1, address);
    }
}
```

I've tried to follow an article on [Enabling Diagnostics in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/), but I can't find any guidance on how to configure the Azure Diagnostics to capture events from my own sources.

Whilst I know the option is there, I'd rather not route my events through the old .NET tracing, as that can only be configured at deployment.

Is there a way to get Azure Diagnostics to pick up my events?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Diagnostics doesn't work with ETW events!

Azure Diagnostics works with:

- Windows Event Log events
- [.NET Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)
- IIS Log files
- Windows Performance Counters
- Custom log files

All of which are very different from ETW ([Event Tracing for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))! ETW is built-into the Windows itself, not the .NET Framework. And Windows Azure Diagnostics module does not have built-in support to read events from ETW. You can however make ETW trace log files and make Azure Diagnostics transfer these logs to a storage as a regular "log" files.

You can read more on how to use ETW trace log files with Windows Azure diagnostics [here](http://www.iconstructions.be/blog/instrument-webrole-with-etw-eventsource-using-windows-azure-diagnostics).

You may also want to take a look at the [Semantic Logging Application Block from the Enterprise Library 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx). This block uses EventSource and has sinks for Windows Azure table storage.

Comment: Considering articles like WAD is built on ETW (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/02/26/wad-is-built-on-etw.aspx), I'm a bit let down by the idea that it doesn't support ETW.

Comment: True, but yet think wisely. It is built on ETW to support high throughput - remember WAD can monitor so many things, it definitely needs a high speed logging mechanism. As to the question why it doesn't support ETW directly. My Speculation is just the amount of data one can very easily generate with ETW. ETW can generate literally 700MB of trace file for couple of minutes. And WAD has to make sure that everything it logs is persisted to a storage. Imagine now my deployment with 10 instances, each one of which doing heavy ETW, and your deployment, and mr.X deployment...

Comment: I'll just have to write my own sink based on http://www.iconstructions.be/blog/instrument-webrole-with-etw-eventsource-using-windows-azure-diagnostics

Comment: Azure SDK 2.5 Adds better support for ETW http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn873976.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Azure now supports ETW logging.  To enable it, in Server Explorer, right-click on the role and edit the diagnostics configuration, there should be a tab for ETW logs where you can enable them.

There's a [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DIY-Windows-Azure-Troubleshooting/WAD-Runtime-Config) Video that explains it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You may also find **[this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics)** useful on how to programmatically enable ETW diagnostics logs on Cloud service.

[image]